# Alternative to static interface method in C#

Tags: c#, interface, static

I have the following situation: I want to identify CSV files by their structure. Structure could simply mean "column names", but one can imagine more complicated structure-definitions which include more attributes of the CSV file. Examples would be "column names and seperator" or "filename satisfies a pattern" and so on.

This is why I wanted to create an interface which all classes that represent such a structure definition need to implement. The simplest definition would be:

```
interface ICSVFormatDefinition {
    bool isFileInThisFormat(string filename);
}
```

However now I would like a static method that analyzes the elements of a file that are needed to define the structure and returns a fitting structure class. Something like this:

```
interface ICSVFormatDefinition {
    bool isFileInThisFormat(string filename);
    static ICSVFormatDefinition createFormatFromFile(string filename);
}
```

The `createFormatFromFile` method in this example would of course be different in every implementation of the interface as one looks only at the filename while another may look at the column names and so on.

However, you cannot declare static methods in an interface in C#. You also cannot declare it as instance method in the interface and implement it static.

My questions are now:

- I guess this is bad design because C# does not allow me to implement it. But why is it bad?
- What is the appropriate way to force all classes that are structure definitions (that implement ICSVFormatDefinition) to have a method to create new instances of themselves?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of Interface is to define a contract for interacting with objects.

Static methods are not for objects. They are for classes.

You probably put the createFormatFromFile() in the wrong place.
Regarding object creation I would suggest Factory/Abstract Factory/Builder design patterns.

Link: http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern

Answer (score 4):

1. Interface declares a **behavior** of object. Static method is not a
   method of object, it's a class one. So, class has no behavior,
   just some utilitarian methods.
2. You can create a factory class, or declare non-static factory method. I think, second way is good for your situation. If your solution depends on `createFormatFromFile` method, it's better to declare it in interface and non static.